# Can Tkinter Treeview Display Images in Any Column Rows As Shown Here?

Tags: tkinter, treeview, ttk, ttkwidgets

I'm able to easily populate and sort the Treeview widget, but I was also wondering if it's possible to add images in any column rows that I want. I've checked all over the net, but was unable to find any examples.

Here's an image displaying exactly what I'm trying to achieve.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7wrI.png)

I'd like to be able to add little image icons to multiple column rows as needed. Anyone know of a way to do it in Tkinter or within some other similar widget? Thanks.

Comment: ttk.Treeview elements have an image option where you can specify an image. Check it here: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html

Comment: No, I'm stating that I'd like to insert images in other columns other than just the 'Phantom' column (not 1st column). I'd like to insert images in last column rows.

Comment: Not sure if these threads get bumped, but I'll try anyhow.